Changes the position from 0 to the left of the screen. I already tried to modify the degrees and the movement of the arrow but I couldn't
I'm starting out in programming and I'm having difficulty creating this graph.
I'm trying to place the graph numbers in order of
0, 45, 90, 174, 178, 90 -45
I'm having trouble placing the 0 to be on the left of the image.
If anyone can give me any tips on how to do this, I would be grateful in advance.
I've already tried a breakpoint to visualize the angle but I didn't get any results.
enter image description here`
import tkinter as tk
import math

class CircleArrowApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("HORSTFX")

        self.radius = 100  # Sets the initial radius of the circles

        # Creating the first circle and its arrow
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(master, width=400, height=400, bg='white', highlightbackground='goldenrod', highlightthickness=15)
        self.canvas1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20)
        self.angle1 = 0
        self.arrow1 = None
        self.canvas1.bind("", self.on_canvas1_resize)

        # Creation of the second circle and its arrow
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(master, width=400, height=400, bg='white', highlightbackground='goldenrod', highlightthickness=15)
        self.canvas2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20)
        self.angle2 = 0
        self.arrow2 = None
        self.canvas2.bind("", self.on_canvas2_resize)

        # Creating the buttons
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10)`

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="START", width=10, command=self.start_animation)
        self.start_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)

        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="STOP", width=10, command=self.stop_animation)
        self.stop_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)

        self.plus_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="+", width=10, command=self.plus_function)
        self.plus_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)

        self.minus_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="-", width=10, command=self.minus_function)
        self.minus_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)

        self.animating = False
        self.animate()

    def start_animation(self):
        self.animating = True

    def stop_animation(self):
        self.animating = False

    def plus_function(self):
        self.radius += 10
        self.update_circle_arrows()

    def minus_function(self):
        if self.radius > 10:
            self.radius -= 10
            self.update_circle_arrows()

    def draw_circle_arrow(self, canvas, angle):
        center_x = canvas.winfo_width() // 2
        center_y = canvas.winfo_height() // 2

        # Set the size of the inner circle relative to the border
        inner_radius = self.radius * 0.8

        # Draw the circle with white fill and yellow border
        canvas.create_oval(center_x - inner_radius, center_y - inner_radius, center_x + inner_radius, center_y + inner_radius, outline='goldenrod', fill='white', width=8)

        # Calculate the arrow's endpoints
        end_x = center_x + inner_radius * math.cos(angle)
        end_y = center_y + inner_radius * math.sin(angle)

        # Draw the arrow moving inside the circle
        start_x = center_x
        start_y = center_y
        canvas.create_line(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill='goldenrod', width=6)
        
        if canvas == self.canvas1:
            if self.arrow1:
                canvas.delete(self.arrow1)
            self.arrow1 = canvas.create_line(center_x, center_y, end_x, end_y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill='goldenrod', width=6)
            # Adiciona os números no círculo exterior do canvas1
            outer_radius = inner_radius + 20
            for i in [0, -135, 90, -45, 0, 45, 90, 135, 178]:
                angle_rad = math.radians(-i)
                num_x = center_x + outer_radius * math.cos(angle_rad)
                num_y = center_y + outer_radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
                canvas.create_text(num_x, num_y, text=str(i), fill='black')

            # Draw the outer circle of canvas1
            outer_radius = inner_radius + 2
            canvas.create_oval(center_x - outer_radius, center_y - outer_radius, center_x + outer_radius, center_y + outer_radius, outline='', width=2)
        elif canvas == self.canvas2:
            if self.arrow2:
                canvas.delete(self.arrow2)
            self.arrow2 = canvas.create_line(center_x, center_y, end_x, end_y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill='goldenrod', width=6)

            # Add the numbers to the outer circle
            outer_radius = inner_radius + 20
            for i in [0, -135, 90, -45, 0, 45, 90, 135, 178]:
                angle_rad = math.radians(-i)
                num_x = center_x + outer_radius * math.cos(angle_rad)
                num_y = center_y + outer_radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
                canvas.create_text(num_x, num_y, text=str(i), fill='black')



Your code sample is not able to be executed. First of all you have certain backticks (`) inside your code, secondly you refer to functions that are not defined.
Please adjust your question to have a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your issue (mvce)

maybe you have to use angle + 180 when you calculate position.  math.radians(-i + 180)

or maybe you have to subtract center_x - ... instead of add center_x + ...  and it should flip items

You may need to use minus instead of plus when you calculate num_x (and eventually num_y) to flip it.
num_x = center_x - radius_outer * math.cos(rad)

or you may need to use angle+180 to rotate it.
rad = math.radians(-angle+180)


Full working example:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=200, height=600)
canvas.pack()

all_angles = [0, 45, 90, 135, 180, -45, -90, -135]

# - version 1 - minus, plus -

center_x = 100
center_y = 100
radius_inner = 50
radius_outer = radius_inner + 25
canvas.create_oval(center_x - radius_inner, center_y - radius_inner, center_x + radius_inner, center_y + radius_inner, width=2)
for angle in all_angles:
    rad = math.radians(-angle)
    num_x = center_x - radius_outer * math.cos(rad)
    num_y = center_y + radius_outer * math.sin(rad)
    canvas.create_text(num_x, num_y, text=str(angle), anchor='center')
canvas.create_text(center_x, center_y, text='minus,plus', anchor='center')

# - version 2 - minus, minus -

center_x = 100
center_y = 300
radius_inner = 50
radius_outer = radius_inner + 25
canvas.create_oval(center_x - radius_inner, center_y - radius_inner, center_x + radius_inner, center_y + radius_inner, width=2)
for angle in all_angles:
    rad = math.radians(-angle)
    num_x = center_x - radius_outer * math.cos(rad)
    num_y = center_y - radius_outer * math.sin(rad)
    canvas.create_text(num_x, num_y, text=str(angle), anchor='center')
canvas.create_text(center_x, center_y, text='minus,minus', anchor='center')

# - version 3 - rotate -

center_x = 100
center_y = 500
radius_inner = 50
radius_outer = radius_inner + 25
canvas.create_oval(center_x - radius_inner, center_y - radius_inner, center_x + radius_inner, center_y + radius_inner, width=2)
for angle in all_angles:
    rad = math.radians(-angle+180)
    num_x = center_x + radius_outer * math.cos(rad)
    num_y = center_y + radius_outer * math.sin(rad)
    canvas.create_text(num_x, num_y, text=str(angle), anchor='center')
canvas.create_text(center_x, center_y, text='angle+180', anchor='center')

root.mainloop()

Result:


I managed to have a much better understanding. It helped a lot.
